# jQuery plugin (Popup Overlay) does not work with more than one div

Tags: jquery, html

I don't understand why this only works with one instance of the popup div. It works correctly in this example html page:

```
  <!-- Add an optional button to open the popup -->
  <button class="my_popup_open">Open popup</button>

  <!-- Add content to the popup -->
  <div id="my_popup">
    <!-- Add an optional button to close the popup -->
    <button class="my_popup_close">Close</button>
<pre>TEST TEXT HERE</pre>
  </div>





  <!-- Include jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include jQuery Popup Overlay -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/1.7.10/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // Initialize the plugin
      $('#my_popup').popup();

    });
  </script>
```

But if I duplicate the div for using it on a page with multiple popups, they all fail, and the content does not start in the "hidden" state as it should. It's displayed outright, and pressing the open popup button causes a page reload.
Example of what fails:

```
<!-- Add an optional button to open the popup -->
  <button class="my_popup_open">Open popup</button>

  <!-- Add content to the popup -->
  <div id="my_popup">
    <!-- Add an optional button to close the popup -->
    <button class="my_popup_close">Close</button>
<pre>{{text}}</pre>
  </div>


  <!-- Add an optional button to open the popup -->
  <button class="my_popup_open">Open popup</button>

  <!-- Add content to the popup -->
  <div id="my_popup">
    <!-- Add an optional button to close the popup -->
    <button class="my_popup_close">Close</button>
<pre>{{text}}</pre>
  </div>

  <!-- Add an optional button to open the popup -->
  <button class="my_popup_open">Open popup</button>

  <!-- Add content to the popup -->
  <div id="my_popup">
    <!-- Add an optional button to close the popup -->
    <button class="my_popup_close">Close</button>
<pre>{{text}}</pre>
  </div>


  <!-- Include jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include jQuery Popup Overlay -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/1.7.10/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // Initialize the plugin
      $('#my_popup').popup();

    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have different element **id** attributes for each popup:
Example:

```
id="my_popup_1", id="my_popup_2"...
```

Also, open and close buttons must have these **classes**:

```
class="my_popup_1_open", class="my_popup_1_close",
class="my_popup_2_open", class="my_popup_2_close"
```

select by formula {id}_open and {id}_close.

Answer (score 1):

You are using your jQuery selectors wrong. You can't have more than one element per page with the same `id`. Try changing the `id` on each popup to `class="my_popup"` instead and your code to:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // Initialize the plugin
      $('.my_popup').popup();

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: I trired that and changing it to the .my_popup causes it to stop functioning at all?

Comment: JQuery popup is meant to be used on links, not divs. If you consult the documentation then you might be able to get it to do what you want it to do. http://docs.toddish.co.uk/popup/demos/

Comment: That's not the exact library I was using so the one you mention may be intended for just links. However, this one (http://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/) works with nearly any element. Your answer did lead me to solving the problem though, thanks!